# Stop modprobe spam

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, dmesg, modprobe

I setup GPU passthrough, it works, but ubuntu is spamming modprobe processes, it consumes lot of CPU, this is log from `dmesg`:

```
[22014.015852] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[22014.019755] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[22014.028669] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 236
[22014.029070] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
[22014.029070] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as: 
               NVRM: nouveau, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv 
               NVRM: was loaded and obtained ownership of the NVIDIA device(s).
[22014.029071] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
               NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
               NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
               NVRM: again.
[22014.029071] NVRM: No NVIDIA devices probed.
[22014.029190] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 236
```

Comment: I can't be specific but I've quite a few complaints about KDE Plasma and NVidia.

Comment: @DKBose I use KDE Plasma

Comment: Have you tried blacklisting `nouveau`?

Comment: I use propriety drivers and I need them.

Comment: @Tomisk Regarding your first comment... [so does Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWzMvlj2RQ)